# R: Populating a data frame with multiple matches for a single value without looping

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a working solution to this problem using a while-loop. I have been made aware that it is typically bad practice to use loops in R so was wondering of alternative approaches.

I have two dataframes, one single-column df full of gene names:

```
head(genes)

   Genes
 1  C1QA
 2  C1QB
 3  C1QC
 4 CSF1R
 5  CTSC
 6  CTSS
```

And a two-column df that has pairs of the gene name (HGNC.symbol) and accompanying ensembl ID (Gene.stable.ID) for each transcript of the given gene:

```
head(ensembl_key)

  Gene.stable.ID     HGNC.symbol
1 ENSG00000210049       MT-TF
2 ENSG00000211459     MT-RNR1
3 ENSG00000210077       MT-TV
4 ENSG00000210082     MT-RNR2
5 ENSG00000209082      MT-TL1
6 ENSG00000198888      MT-ND1
```

My goal is to create a df that for each gene in the `genes` df extracts all corresponding transcript ID's (Gene.stable.ID) from the `ensembl_key` df.

The reason I have only found the looping solution is because a single entry in `genes` may have multiple matches in `ensembl_key`. I need to retain all matches and include them in the final df and I also do not know the number of matches a single ID from `genes` has a priori.

Here is my current working solution:

```
# Create large empty df to hold all transcripts
gene_transcript<- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow= 5000, ncol= 2))
colnames(gene_transcript)<- c("geneID", "ensemblID")

# Populate Ensembl column
curr_gene<- 1
gene_count<- 1
while(gene_count <= dim(genes)[1]){
  transcripts<- ensembl_key[which(ensembl_key$HGNC.symbol==  genes$Genes[gene_count]),1]

  if(length(transcripts)>1){
    num<- length(transcripts)-1

    gene_transcript$geneID[curr_gene:(curr_gene+num)]<- genes$Genes[curr_gene]
    gene_transcript$ensemblID[curr_gene:(curr_gene+num)]<- transcripts

    gene_count<- gene_count+1
    curr_gene<- curr_gene + num + 1
  }
  else{
    gene_transcript$geneID[curr_gene]<- genes$Genes[curr_gene]
    gene_transcript$ensemblID[curr_gene]<- transcripts

    gene_count<- gene_count+1
    curr_gene<- curr_gene + 1
  }
}

# Remove unneccessary columns
last_row<- which(is.na(gene_transcript$geneID)==T)[1]-1
gene_transcript<- gene_transcript[1:last_row,]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to join or merge. Several ways to do this, but the following should work.

```
merge(genes, 
      ensembl_key,
      by.x = "Genes",
      by.y = "HGNC.symbol")
```